# Is there a way to get all complete sentences that a search engine (e.g. Google) has indexed that contain two search terms?

Tags: search, search-engine

as the question says: "Is there a way to get all complete sentences that a search engine (e.g. Google) has indexed that contain two search terms?"

I would like to use the (e.g. Google) search syntax: BMW AND Toyota. (<-- this is just an example)
And I would then like to have returned all sentences that mention BMW and Toyota. They must be in a single (ideally: short) sentence though.

Is that possible?

Many thanks!

PS.: Sorry - I have difficulties finding the right tags for my question... Please feel free to suggest more appropriate ones and I will update the question.

PPS.: Let me rephrase my question: If it is not readily possible with an existing search engine, are there any programmatical ways to do that? Would one have to write a crawler for that purpose?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming nor do I know of a site in the Stack Exchange network where this would be in topic

Comment: Asking if this is possible for a specific search engine might be on-topic on [webapps.se]. Asking for a search engine that can do this might be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se]. Asking for an (openly licensed) index that contains such data (i.e., sentences) might be on-topic on [opendata.se].

Answer (score 1):

No this may not be possible, as google stores this info based on keywords and other algorithms.

For any given keyword or set of keywords, google must be maintaining a reference to one or many matching (some accurate, some not so accurate) titles.

I do not work for google, but that could one way they are maintaining their search results.